# JavaScript image won't display when hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a carousel that displays images with an interval.
When an image is displayed, a text(3 heading images) to the left is wrapped with a border.
I want the images to be displayed on the right side every time I hover over a specific text heading on the left. Still, can't figure out how to do it.
Say, if a user hovers on the 1st slide, I simply tried to display it and setting the rest two slides to none which didn't work.

```js
var pr1 = document.querySelector('.pr1'); 
var pr2 = document.querySelector('.pr2');
var pr3 = document.querySelector('.pr3');
var slide1 = document.querySelector('.slide1');
var slide2 = document.querySelector('.slide2');
var slide3 = document.querySelector('.slide3');
var slideImg1 = document.querySelector('.slideImg1');
var slideImg2 = document.querySelector('.slideImg2');
var slideImg3 = document.querySelector('.slideImg3');
var img1Path = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511404178/v_erp_w8eyhx.png')";
var img2Path = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511404178/v_aps_htif6m.png')";
var img3Path = "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511404178/v_dbr_kt31ej.png')";
var slide1Bool = false;
var slide2Bool = false;
var slide3Bool = false;

pr1.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver1);
function mouseOver1() {
  pauseTheLoop();
 slide1.style.display = 'block'; 
  console.log('mouseOver1');
  slide2.style.display = 'none';
    slide3.style.display = 'none';
 /* alert('mouseOver1');*/

  if(slide2Bool || slide3Bool) {  
    pr1.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    pr1.style.borderRight = '1px solid #fff';
    pr2.style.border = 'none';
    pr3.style.border = 'none';
  }
}

pr1.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut1);
function mouseOut1() {
  pr1.style.border = 'none';
  console.log('mouseOut1');
}

pr2.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver2);
function mouseOver2() {
  pauseTheLoop();
  slide2.style.display = 'block';
     slide1.style.display = 'none';
    slide3.style.display = 'none';
/*  alert('mouseOver2');*/
  console.log('mouseOver2');
  if(slide1Bool || slide3Bool) {
    pr2.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    pr2.style.borderRight = '1px solid #fff';
    pr1.style.border = 'none';
    pr3.style.border = 'none';
  }
}
pr2.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut2);
function mouseOut2() {
  console.log('mouseOut2');
  pr2.style.border = 'none';
}

pr3.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver3);
function mouseOver3() {
  pauseTheLoop();
  slide2.style.display = 'block';
  console.log('mouseOver3');
  if(slide1Bool || slide2Bool) {
    pr3.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    pr3.style.borderRight = '1px solid #fff';
    pr1.style.border = 'none';
    pr2.style.border = 'none';
    slide1.style.display = 'none';
    slide2.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
pr3.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut3);
function mouseOut3() {
  console.log('mouseOut3');
  pr3.style.border = 'none';
}

var slideIndex = 0;
var timer;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var index;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
  for(index=0;index<slides.length;index++) {
    slides[index].style.display = 'none';
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if(slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;}
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = 'block';
  if(slides[0].style.display == 'block'){
    slide1Bool = true;
    console.log('slide1Bool = true');
    pr1.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    pr1.style.borderRight = '1px solid #fff';
  } else {
    slide1Bool = false;
    console.log('slide1Bool = false');
    pr1.style.border = 'none';
  }

  if(slides[1].style.display == 'block'){
    slide2Bool = true;
    console.log('slide2Bool = true');
    pr2.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    pr2.style.borderRight = '1px solid #fff';
  } else {
    slide2Bool = false;
    console.log('slide2Bool = false');
    pr2.style.border = 'none';
  }

  if(slides[2].style.display == 'block'){
    slide3Bool = true;
    console.log('slide3Bool = true');
    pr3.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    pr3.style.borderRight = '1px solid #fff';
  } else {
    slide3Bool = false;
    console.log('slide3Bool = false');
    pr3.style.border = 'none';
  }
  timer = setTimeout(function() {carousel();},1000);
}

function pauseTheLoop() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){carousel();},1000);
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanskr.css);
.sol_info {font-family:'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif; width:325px;height:220px;}
.s_lgnd {display:inline-block;width:160px;height:30px;vertical-align:middle;position:relative;}
.s_lgnd img {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;margin: auto;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 9px 6px -5px #ced2dd;-moz-box-shadow: 0 9px 6px -5px #ced2dd;box-shadow: 0 9px 6px -5px #ced2dd;}
.sol_info > a {display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-size:13px;background:#00076d;padding:2px 2px 4px;border-radius:6px;text-transform:capitalize;margin-left:15px;margin-right:30px;}

.pr_name {display:inline-block;position:relative;margin-top:10px;/*outline:1px solid pink;*/}
.pr_name > a {width:110px;height:35px;display:block;border-bottom-left-radius:7px; border-top-left-radius:7px;}
.pr_name > a img {display:block;position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);}
.pr_name > a:hover {border:1px solid #ccc !important;border-right:1px solid #fff !important;z-index:12;}
.pr_name > span {position:absolute;display:block;width:1px; height:170px; background:#ccc; left:111px;top:-15px;z-index:-1;}

.pr_img_gal {display:inline-block;padding:0;margin:0;position:absolute; left:135px; top:40px; width:175px; height:165px; overflow:hidden;}
.pr_img_gal > li {margin-left:4px;margin-right:5px;display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="sol_info">
  <div class="s_lgnd"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511402376/sol_info_img_hzzpo5.jpg" alt="Solutins Information"></div><a href="#">go</a>
  <div class="pr_name">
    <a class="pr1" href="#"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511404178/v_erp_w8eyhx.png" alt="Visual ERP"></a>
    <a class="pr2" href="#"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511404178/v_aps_htif6m.png" alt="Visual APS"></a>
    <a class="pr3" href="#"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511404178/v_dbr_kt31ej.png" alt="Visual DBR"></a>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul class="pr_img_gal">
      <li class="mySlides slide1"><a href="#"><img class="slideImg1" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511407337/slide1_ibzjlw.jpg" alt="Visual ERP"></a></li>
      <li class="mySlides slide1"><a href="#"><img class="slideImg2" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511407337/slide2_ysuho2.jpg" alt="Visual APS"></a></li>
      <li class="mySlides slide1"><a href="#"><img class="slideImg3" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dijc9b7wz/image/upload/v1511407337/slide3_zcpskg.jpg" alt="Visual DBR"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
slide1.style.display = 'block'; 
slide2.style.display = 'none';
slide3.style.display = 'none';
```

The structure is as follows:
The carousel that displays images and gives borders to the headings on the left.
For each heading, I have event listeners mouseover and mouseout.
So far they only work when changing borders.

Comment: All of your image `li` have class `slide1`, shouldn't it be `slide2` and `slide3` for slide number 2 and 3?

Comment: @azs06 Yes. Thanks, my bad... A good reminder to double-check all class names and variables to prevent possible problems..

Comment: does this fixes the issue you were having?

Comment: Yes. pretty much It did.